# Парсинг JSON с динамическим содержимым

Tags: java, json, gson

не совсем понимаю как парсить json с динамическими элементами внутри.
API возвращает ответ вида:
`{"cmd_id":{"7898616":995702}}`
где значения в cmd_id динамические.
Как сделать модель, чтобы передавать ее в Gson?

Answer (score 1):

Нашел ответ, можно использовать java.util.Map

```
    @SerializedName("cmd_id")
    @Expose
    private Map<Long,Long> cmdId;
```